# second derivative implicit differentiation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How does $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-1}{4y^3}$ if $x-y^2 = 1$? I'm getting conflicting answers on all the online calculators.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with, including the details of what conflicting answers you get.  The exercise seems intended to help learn about implicit differentiation, but the little you wrote might apply to almost any kind of problem.

Comment: Have you noticed that $x=y^2+1$? You can easily find $x^\prime$ and use the derivative of an inverse.

Comment: To start you off $1-2y \frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: the answers are not likely conflicting but equivalent. this happens whenever $y$ is not given explicitly. these equations/constraints are called implicit so you always have to carry the constraint along.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you provided a screenshot of the conflicting answers you are getting on each of the online calculators.

Answer (score 2):

you have $$x-y^2=1$$ and $$y=y(x)$$ thus we get $$1-2yy'=0$$ or $$y'=\frac{1}{2}y^{-1}$$ from here we get $$y''=\frac{1}{2}(-1)y^{-2}y'$$ and you can plug $$y'$$ in this equation
$$y''=-\frac{1}{4y^3}$$